# Save date on every form submission Django

Tags: django, forms, date

Would it be possible to save the exact date when a specific user submits the form without updating existing data? So basically I'd have every date when a user submitted the form. I'd want to use these dates for a graph. When I submit the form now it updates the user's data, such as weight, height, and goal. It works fine, but I want to be able to save submission days like "2020.09.12". And if the user submits the form again to change his data the date should containt "2020.09.12" + the new date.

What I want to achieve is this: If a specific user submits the form for example 5 times than I want to have 5 dates to work with.

**UPDATE**

> Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='user_profile')
weight = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
height = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
goal = models.FloatField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
 def save_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
  if created:
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  #else:
  # instance.user_profile.save() #UPDATE
```

> view

```
def get_data(request, *args,**kwargs):
data = {
    'weight': request.user.user_profile.weight,
    'goal': request.user.user_profile.goal,
    'date': request.user.user_profile.created_at,
}

return JsonResponse(data)
```

> Ajax

```
var endpoint = '/api/data';
var defaultDataW = [];
var defaultDataG = [];
var dates = [];

$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data.weight);
        console.log(data.goal);
        console.log(data.date);
 },
 error: function(error_data){
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(error_data);
    }
})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model for saving the historical data. It will be bound to the user via `ForeignKey`, and add there an extra column for the date. Use [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) parameter there to set the current date automatically during saving.

```
class UserData(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
    weight = models.IntegerField(...)
    # other columns to store
    # the following column has information when the data was created
    created_at = models.DateField(..., auto_now_add=True)
```

When you want to display the data, load the record with latest date.

Comment: Hello! I did as you said, but when I submit the form for example 3 times than I should be able to access 3 date values right?  Cuz I did an ajax request to send the values to my js and when I console.log it I only get 1 date instead of 3.

Comment: You didnt show any code, so from my side it's just guessing. If your ajax does not work as expected, that's too bad. But again - no code means no specific advice, just guessing.

Comment: you're not using ForeignKey, but [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), which has the constraint that there can be only one record per user.